# Conditionally enable member function depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling to get the below code to compile. I want to enable `foo` function for class `A` only when `N=3`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    template <size_t n = N, std::enable_if_t<(n == 3)>* = nullptr> int foo(int a);
};

template<size_t N> 
template <size_t n = N, std::enable_if_t<(n == 3)>* = nullptr>
int A<N>::foo(int a)
{
    return a * 4;
}

int main()
{
    A<3> a1;
    std::cout << a1.foo(10) << std::endl;

    // the below should fail to compile
    // A<4> a2;
    // std::cout << a2.foo(7) << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
<source>:12:20: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'int A<N>::foo(int)'
   12 | int A<N>::foo(int a)
      |                    ^
```

Comment: Simply move the function's implementation into the class declaration inline and the error goes away.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know but I prefer to implement methods outside the class.

Comment: templates are different, they are much more difficult to implement that way. They are better off implemented inlined.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Are you saying it is impossible?

Comment: no, it is possible ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vd3o3rGr5)). I'll write an answer, one sec...

Comment: _I prefer to implement methods outside the class_ Why?  This is usually only done for a reason.

Comment: @PaulSanders In my project, all of my other class methods are implemented outside the class and it would look ugly to me if I make exception by having one of the methods implemented inside the class.

Comment: @RaySiplao You might like to reconsider that.  Implementing small, frequently called methods in the class definition can help the compiler inline (or otherwise optimise) your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you separate a function's declaration and definition, whether it is a template function or not, default argument values can only be in the declaration, not in the definition. So, simply remove the default values from foo's definition, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    template <size_t n = N, std::enable_if_t<(n == 3)>* = nullptr> int foo(int a);
};

template<size_t N> 
template <size_t n, std::enable_if_t<(n == 3)>*>
int A<N>::foo(int a)
{
    return a * 4;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cEKs3M4sT)